# boot menu shows multi Ubuntu grub's and Cannot shut down operatin

Tags: boot, shutdown

I cannot remove multiple Ubuntu boot options that show up in my boot menu. I updated to 17.04 and it had so many issues that I deleted it and reinstalled Ubuntu.

I couldn't get the new operating system installer to boot without changing "quiet splash" to "nomodeset".

Now once my new operating system is installed it will not shut down. I changed the grub file line to what people suggest. The only way my computer will now shut down is if i change the grub config file from " quite splash" to nomodset. When that is done the operating system opens and closes but resolution is all skrewed up.

I really want to remove everything and start fresh. So remove both of the options from my boot sector and  remove the  operating system and start fresh. Have found many techniques. Though nothing has worked to fix the shutdown problem or helped me remove the boot sector options.

Help

Comment: Won't let me post a picture of my boot menu

Comment: are you booting in Legacy mode with an MBR disk?

Comment: What brand/model system and what video card/chip? If you  still need nomodeset, did you not install the correct proprietary driver for your video card?

Comment: Ravery, yes i tried both. Razer blade16 970m video. And yes I still need need nomodeset if I want the operating system to shut down. If it's not set. The computer hangs up instantly on shutdown. Last time I installed Ubuntu it handled my driver's and ran fine. Can video drives cause it not to shut down?